# Crystal reports not showing records returned by sql query

Tags: database, vb.net, crystal-reports, oledb

I am using crystal reports to print invoice.

it consist of fields from multiple tables.

I have created oledbcommand, Oledbdataadapter and dataset to display results in crystal report.

Problem:

If I put details of Customer in "Page header" section of crystal report it only shows the first record

and if I put them in "Details" section of crystal report it shows all the records.

I have varified the data returned by sql query by showing the result in a datagrid, there the data returned is correct.

So please someone help me with this issue.

P.S. : I am using Ms Access database.

and I have only a little knoledge of crystal report so I might have made a silly mistake.

If possible please upload the whole code to print multiple database tables onto a crystal report.

I'm really STUCK so please HELP

Code:

```
bcmd = New OleDbCommand
bcmd.Connection = Functions.dbcon
bcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Item where Item_ID = 16"
bcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

bda = New OleDbDataAdapter(bcmd)
bds = New DataSet

bda.Fill(bds)

rptdoc.load("full absolute path")  // file exists here , so no issues with it 

rptdoc.setdatasource(bds.tables(0))

repview.reportsource = rptdoc
```

Comment: You say if you put the fields into the Details section then it shows all records... What exactly is the issue, then?

Comment: It should show specific records filtered by sql query

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @user3762349, you need to be a little more detailed.  Can you please describe your filter?  Are you saying that there are values on the report that should be removed by the filter?  Are you saying that you aren't seeing all the columns you expect?

Comment: Even if I have used where clause it shows all records

Comment: or sometimes it just not load the report in the viewer even if it exists

Comment: Create a new group for customer on customer_ID and then put Customer details on the group. That i think should do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the support,

I guess I have found the solution.

to print specific records that matches a criteria, you can use

***rptdoc.RecordSelectionFormula property***

provide field name --> {table name.column name} = value